# Ghost Element (Drag Element) is not visible in CEFSharp (ChromiumWebBrowser)

Tags: angular, typescript, drag-and-drop, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I developed angular application and it has drag and drop feature. I'm loading this angular application into ChromiumWebBrowser and it is loading successfully. The problem here is while dragging an element, it should show the ghost element but in ChromiumWebBrowser it is not showing. Same angular application if loaded directly into web browser(Tested in Google Chrome) the ghost element is visible

To make it more understandable I have added two reference images. One without ghost image(Google offered in) which is loaded into ChromiumWebBrowser and another one with ghost image(Google offered in) which is loaded directly into Google Chrome Web Browser

[image: Without GhostImage loaded into ChromiumWebBrowser]

[image: With GhostImage loaded directly into Google Chrome Web Browser]

Code Sample :

```
        ChromiumWebBrowser Browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();          
        Browser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (Browser.IsBrowserInitialized)
            {
                Browser.AllowDrop = true;
                Browser.Load("https://www.google.com");
            }
        };
```

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF? In WPF that hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: @amaitland I'm using WPF. Is there anyway to achieve that?.

Comment: @amaitland If I use @angular/cdk library seems it is achievable. But I don't want to use any library.

Comment: One alternative is to use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.Wpf.HwndHost#cefsharpwpfhwndhost which is similar to hosting the WinForms version in WPF, airspace issues apply.

Comment: Another option is to rebase the https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/2687 unfinished pull request on master and see if that adds support.